# searching a database for partial matches on strings.(python)

Tags: algorithm, debugging, python-3.x

I am trying to implement prims algorithm for finding the MST of a graph.  I am given an adjacency list of nodes in the graph. EX: [[10001, 5, 8, 4], [5, 10001, 6, 9], [8, 6, 10001, 10], [4, 9, 10, 10001]] where the number is the length between node i and j.

I implemented the following code to check create the edges and return the list edges in the mst.  However, cannot seem to get the right answer.

here is my code.

```
def find_MST(n, length):
      print(length) #this is only for debugging purposes
      n = len(length)
      dist = [float('inf') for i in range(n)]
      prev = [None for i in range(n)]
      done = [False for i in range(n)]
      dist[0] = 0
      q = [i for i in range(len(length))]
      while len(q) > 0:
        smaller = MAX_LENGTH
        for i in q:
          if dist[i] < smaller:
            smaller = dist[i]
            pos = i
        u = q[q.index(pos)]
        q.pop(q.index(pos))
        if dist[u] == float('inf'):
              break    
        for v in range(len(length[u])):
          alt = length[u][v]
          if dist[v] > alt:
            dist[v] = alt
            prev[v] = u  

      l = []      
      for i in range(len(prev)):
        if prev[i] != None:
            edge = (min(prev[i],i), max(prev[i], i))    
            l.append(edge)

      return l
```

can anybode let me know what I should change to make it give the correct output?

here is an example:
where each line is a different test case
my output:

```
(0, 1)
(0, 2) (1, 2)
(0, 1) (2, 3) (2, 3)
(0, 1) (0, 2) (0, 3)
(0, 1) (0, 3) (1, 2)
```

correct output:

```
(0, 1)
(0, 2) (1, 2)
(0, 1) (0, 3) (2, 3)
(0, 1) (0, 2) (0, 3)
(0, 1) (0, 3) (1, 2)
```

Comment: Also, sorry forthe inconvenience, i just noticed that the title does not match the question.  My fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who wants to know, i fixed this.  ended up comparing every edge with the smallest one multiple times to find the absolute smallest.  This implementation was correct had it not been for the negative edges.  What I had to do was remove the while loop and q, then add 2 more for loops just before the first one in such a manner:

```
    for i in range(len(length)):
         for u in range(len(length)):
               for v in range len(length[u]):
```

then i continued with the rest of the code.

THIS WHOLE BLOCK OF CODE BECOMES OBSOLETE:

```
while len(q) > 0:
    smaller = MAX_LENGTH
    for i in q:
      if dist[i] < smaller:
        smaller = dist[i]
        pos = i
    u = q[q.index(pos)]
    q.pop(q.index(pos))
    if dist[u] == float('inf'):
          break
```